# Breeze filtering not working

Tags: filter, breeze, client-side, single-page-application

I am using breeze and the filter does not work.

```
var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;
var manager = configureBreezeManager("xxx");

function configureBreezeManager(param) {
   breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
   var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager(param);
   model.configureMetadataStore(mgr.metadataStore);
   return mgr;
}
```

And my query query

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('GetStudents').where("Id", "==", "xxx");
 return manager.executeQuery(query)
```

The filter is ignore and all results are returned. my get student returns an IQueryable of all students.

```
public IQueryable<Students> GetStudents(){
     return context.Students;
}
```

Is there something up there I am doing wrong or should I look elsewhere?

**EDIT**
I realize that my controller is missing the property [BreezeController]. But when I include that, me metadata path is not found giving me an error (error 500 below) when trying to load it. The matadata loads fine without this property on the controller, but filtering does not work. Is this related?

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.OData, ... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

Comment: What does your server endpoint look like?

Comment: There is no error on the server. Seems where clause(or any other) is simply ignored. I am now looking for a basic tutorial. I can't even fetch by key without getting an error saying the metadata is missing.

Comment: I'm not looking for an error, I want to see if you are returning an IQueryable<T>.

Comment: Yes. I am. Please see edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the [BreezeController] and after adding it, I received the error `Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Http.OData, Version=4.0.0.0` and was able to solve it by runing `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData` in the package manager

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be that you have specified a 'camelCase' namingConvention, but your query is for 'Id' instead of 'id'.  i.e. try:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('GetStudents').where("id", "==", "xxx");
return manager.executeQuery(query)
```

Comment: Tried that but did not work. I realize that my controller is missing the property [BreezeController]. But when I include that, me metadata path is not found giving me an error (500) when trying to load it. The matadata loads fine without this property on the controller, but filtering does not work. Is this related?